# ios 6: UIDatePicker in the UITextField

Tags: ios, ios6, datepicker, uitextfield

I have problems with connecting datepicker with text field. I have tried all solution from stackoverflow but they don't work in ios 6. Can you desribe how to make it, I want to tap on text field and choose date via datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `inputView` property of your `UITextField` to make the picker show in place of the keyboard. iOS6 will take care of everything for you then (showing the picker with the animation instead of the keyboard, etc).

*Note: You will probably want to add some `inputAccessoryView` too (generally an `UIToolBar` with some "OK" button in it) to make the user be able to dismiss the picker (the `IBAction` of your "OK" button will simply call `[textField resignFirstResponder]` for that to happen of course) as an `UIDatePicker` does not have any button to validate your input (whereas the keyboard has its "Return Key")*

Answer (score -2):

```
#import "TextfieldwithDatepickerViewController.h"

UIActionSheet *pickerViewPopup;

@implementation TextfieldwithDatepickerViewController
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)aTextField{  
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];  

    pickerViewPopup = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];  

    UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0)];  
    pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;  
    pickerView.hidden = NO;  
    pickerView.date = [NSDate date];  

    UIToolbar *pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];  
    pickerToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;  
    [pickerToolbar sizeToFit];  

    NSMutableArray *barItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];  
    [barItems addObject:flexSpace];  

    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonPressed:)];  
    [barItems addObject:doneBtn];  

    UIBarButtonItem *cancelBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonPressed:)];  
    [barItems addObject:cancelBtn];  

    [pickerToolbar setItems:barItems animated:YES];  

    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerToolbar];  
    [pickerViewPopup addSubview:pickerView];  
    [pickerViewPopup showInView:self.view];  
    [pickerViewPopup setBounds:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 464)];  
}  

-(void)doneButtonPressed:(id)sender{  
    //Do something here here with the value selected using [pickerView date] to get that value  

    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];  
}  

-(void)cancelButtonPressed:(id)sender{  
    [pickerViewPopup dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:1 animated:YES];  
}
```

Comment: I made it, it compiled and started but pickview or picktoolbar weren't appear. Just standart keyboard appeared. Can you give me source of project with datepicker in the text field ? maybe you can put it to github ?